# Addressing Variability in Telegram User Data Retrieval: Understanding Inconsistent Results and Seeking Solutions with Python and the Telegram API

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am encountering unexpected variations in data retrieval while attempting to fetch user information from Telegram channels and groups using my code. For instance, when pulling data from the same channel or group, I sometimes successfully retrieve 50 out of 100 members, while other times I can only retrieve 3 or fewer members. I am seeking assistance to understand the potential reasons behind this issue and to identify steps I can take to address it while working with the Telegram API.

Additionally, below is a code snippet illustrating the problem:

```
# Initialize a flag to control user data retrieval
user_data_flag = 0

# Set the maximum number of participants to retrieve in each request
limit = 100

# Initialize the offset (starting point for retrieval)
offset = 0

# Create an empty list to store all retrieved participants
all_participants = []

# Check if user data retrieval is enabled
if user_data_flag == 0:
    # Define a list of query keys (letters 'a' to 'z') to search for participants
    queryKey = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    
    # Iterate through each query key
    for key in queryKey:
        # Print the current query key being processed
        print(f"The Key is {key}\n")
        
        # Send a request to the Telegram API to retrieve participants whose usernames start with the current key
        participants = await client(GetParticipantsRequest(
            my_channel, ChannelParticipantsSearch(key), offset, limit,
            hash=0
        ))

        # Check if there are no participants returned
        if not participants.users:
            break

        # Iterate through each user in the returned participants
        for user in participants.users:
            try:
                # Check if the first letter of the username (converted to lowercase) matches the current key
                if re.findall(r"\b[a-zA-Z]", user.username)[0].lower() == key:
                    # Print the user's information
                    print("USER ---->", user, "\n")
                    
                    # Append the user's information to the list of all participants
                    all_participants.append(user)
                    
                    # Reset the unused variable 'c' to 0
                    c = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Telegram's API intentionally does not want users fetching all members to reduce abuse. There is no way around this, as the server dictates the rules.

Furthermore, some of these activities may be seen as suspicious by Telegram, and may lead to account bans.

Comment: Is there a way or method we can overcome this rule?